# How many possibilities in tinyurl

Tags: permutations

Looking at tinyurl, there is anywhere from 1 digit to 7 digits of I believe 36 choices (lowercase letters a to z and digits 0 to 9)

How do I calculate mathmatically the number of permutations of the string with 1 to 7 digits and 36 characters?

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$36^1+36^2+36^3+36^4+36^5+36^6+36^7=80,603,140,212$$

Comment: ah, duh.....we nearly had that and it made perfect sense when we saw it.

Comment: Or possibly even $$\frac{36^8-1}{35}-1$$ ;)

Answer (score 1):

The number of permutations (without replacement) of size $k$ on an alphabet of size $n$ is $n^k$. If you just need an approximate answer, the term $36^7$ is by far the largest, but if you want an exact answer, you can sum from $k=1$ to $k=7$.

Answer (score -3):

I was just wondering the same thing.. Look up factorials - "The factorial $n!$ gives the number of ways in which $n$ objects can be permuted."

Given $26$ characters and $10$ numerals, $36!= 3.72\times 10^{41}$,  a fair sized number! Tinyurl can repeat characters,  which reduces the overall combinations.

I don't know if tinyurl does capital letters as well, but if they do then they aren't ever going to run out - $66!= 5.4\times 10^{92}$.

Comment: This answer, unfortunately, is incorrect. TinyURL isn't permuting 36 objects. They are making a string of length up to seven, each character of which is one of 36 choices. Those things are different.